# Turn search on page into live search on page

Tags: javascript, html, search

Search on page, with highlighting matches, as Ctrl+F in browser. But only it won't start searching until you press the button. At the same time, you have to click it to highlight each of the matches. In general, please help me make it "live"

```js
superfind = function() {
  var surround = document.createElement('span');
  surround.style.background = '#e9bd13';

  return function(str) {
    var sel = getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();

    if (surround.hasChildNodes()) {
      sel.collapse(surround.nextSibling, 0);

      var temp = document.createDocumentFragment();
      while (surround.hasChildNodes()) temp.appendChild(surround.firstChild);
      surround.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, surround); //return it as it was
    }

    while (sel.isCollapsed) { //search until something found in  document (not in input)
      if (!find(str)) { //and until the document ends
        return false
      }
    }
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.surroundContents(surround);
    sel.collapse(surround, 1);

    return true
  }
}();
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="superfind(nextSibling.value)" /><input type="text" placeholder="Find something..." />

<p>Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for anyone that codes to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers. More than 50 million unique visitors come to Stack Overflow each month to help solve coding problems,
  develop new skills, and find job opportunities.</p>

<p>Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for anyone that codes to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers. More than 50 million unique visitors come to Stack Overflow each month to help solve coding problems,
  develop new skills, and find job opportunities.</p>

<p>Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for anyone that codes to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers. More than 50 million unique visitors come to Stack Overflow each month to help solve coding problems,
  develop new skills, and find job opportunities.</p>
```

I think needs to do something with *onchange* but I don't know how. Help me please...

Comment: Where do you assign `nextSibling`? I suspect you're getting an error from `nextSibling.value`. And the function doesn't even use its argument.

Comment: I think you mean `this.nextSibling.value`

Answer (score -1):

Try using `oninput` rather than `onclick`

```
<input type="button" value="Search"/><input type="text" placeholder="Find something..."  oninput="superfind(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: Yea, but then I have to click on the input line after entering each letter to activate it again. And so every letter. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: @FiftyFour7250 I'm not sure i know what you're asking.

Comment: Just try it https://codepen.io/fiftyfour7250/pen/ZELJGwj Try to find any word